# Opacity change on image while hovering overlaying text

Tags: html, css

I have an image that changes opacity on hover. the image has text overlay. I want the image opacity to change while hovering the text as well.

Any ideas?

```css
.main {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image {
  width: 20%;
  opacity: .5;
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 800%;
  color: white;
  top: 20%;
  left: 6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="" />
  <p class="text">lite text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the hover style on an element wrapping both the image and the text.

Comment: Encapsulating all elements inside a div and using hover property for that div will work for all elements inside the div.

Comment: it's worth saying that if you'll use a container controlling the hover style, such event will be triggered when any point of its area will be hovered.. so including also the text you'll be embedding inside that same container. if you instead meant only the picture to be in charge of the hover event and still wanted to use css only it would require a more elaborate strategy. With js it would be much easier of course. But I'm just throwing thoughts at the problem to enrich the awarness of the issue .. I didn't mean to suggest actual solutions

Answer (score 0):

Add your opacity attribute to the `.main` div instead of the `.image`

CSS:

```css
.main {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.main:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.image {
    width: 20%;
}

.text {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 800%;
    color: white;
    top: 20%;
    left: 6%; 
}
```